# Django OneToOneField, ManyToManyField, Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, one-to-one, django-orm

I've read many posts on what OneToOneField, ManyToManyField, and Foreign Key are but they aren't very clear. I am very new to Django and python programming, currently trying to develop models. Can someone explain to me in simple language, preferably with example, what they each are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagine a database, which stores your book collection:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, primary_key=True)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

**One-to-many/Foreign Key**

Every `Book` has one `Publisher`, but a `Publisher` might have published multiple books. Therefore they are in a one-to-many (book-to-publisher) relationship.

**One-to-one**

Every `Publisher` is located in one `Place`, and every `Place` can only hold one `Publisher`. Therefore they are in a one-to-one relationship. You could just have well have put the `Place` information (`address` and `country`) with the `Publisher` model in one table, but sometimes it is preferred to have seperate models. For example, if you do not know the `Place` for every `Publisher`, you don't need to take up a lot of space with empty rows.

**Many-to-many**

Every `Book` also has one or more `Author`s. However, an `Author` might have written multiple `Book`s, so they are in a many-to-many relationship.

*If you still need some guidance, I suggest taking a look at [the model chapter of the Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html).*

Comment: Excellent answer. I would also suggest the OP to read about database relationships, as they apply directly these Django fields. Try this - http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: This cleared everything up for me! Thank you very much! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to up your answer =/